# What algorithm can I use for pattern-matching on line charts?

Tags: algorithm, charts, distance, similarity

I have a line chart A, a set of pairs `(x, y)`. I have another line chart B, a set of such pairs as well.

What algorithms can I use for finding patterns between those two charts? Informally, by a ***pattern*** I mean *parts of those two charts where the way a line behaves is similar*.

How to approach the issue? I only seek the names of algorithms or ways such problems are approached, nothing more.

Comment: Are the x positions evenly spaced?  If so, one option would be to convert all y values to deltas and use DP to perform a type of approximate substring matching in which the match penalty is proportional to the difference between corresponding deltas.  Easy and fast, but this will allow errors to accumulate in long matches (more of an issue if deviations are biased in one direction).  If the x positions aren't evenly spaced, then you need to decide carefully on a criterion to optimise -- how should same-width regions with different numbers of points be compared with each other?

Comment: If the x positions aren't evenly spaced, then another option you have is to *make them evenly spaced*, by sampling the plot at regular x intervals.  (This also lets you incorporate some smoothing if you want.)  This can miss small fluctuations, but that can be alleviated by increasing the sampling rate.

Comment: cross-correlation, convolution, signal processing